# Can anyone tell me how to do check response and request from database using jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

I need to verify the request and response from back-end in jmeter using java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more information to the question. What you have tried, what is not working, some example output you would like to see. Actually information in any form as this is not well structured for a question. Try to explain the process and the desired outcome.

Comment: I guess the correct answer to this question is "yes", because someone will be able to answer it, even though most likely noone will do it unless you improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter provides [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler to execute database queries and [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) to conditionally set pass/fail criteria

See the following articles to get started:

- [Building a Database Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html)
- [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter)